# awk script to check if file exists and combine lines from files

Tags: oracle, awk

I am working on a sqlldr script to load data into Oracle tables.  It generates 3 files, a log file, bad data file and discarded records file.

I found a nifty script on the net that parses these files and associates errors from log files with appropriate records.  I do not remember the site where I found it.  I now want to add a check to the script to check if these files exist and for that I am trying to understand the script so I can add the logic.

I have not done awk before.

Here is the script.  Please can someone explain what the first 4 lines do?

```
awk '
FNR==1 { FileNum++ }
FileNum==1 { Bad[FNR] = $0 ; next }
FileNum==2 { Dis[FNR] = $0 ; next }
/^Record [0-9]+: Rejected/ {
   rec = Bad[++Rejected];
   col = $NF;
   getline;
   sub(/^ORA-[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/, "");
   print rec, "Error on column", col;
   next;
}
/^Record [0-9]+: Discarded/ {
   rec = Dis[++discarded];
   sub(/.*Discarded - /, "")
   print rec, $0;
   next;
}
' file.bad file.discarded file.log
```

**UPDATE**
**======**

**@Ed -  example below**

Adding the example of files and expected output

After sqlldr finishes execution, three files are creted, 
- Log file
- Bad data file and
- discarded records file

The log file will have the control file and then any errors are logged

e.g.

`Record 5: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses`.  -- This goes to discarded file

-- the below 2 go to bad data file

```
Record 6: Rejected - Error on table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated

Record 7: Rejected - Error on table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated

**Log file**
Record 5: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses

Record 6: Rejected - Error on table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated

Record 7: Rejected - Error on table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated

**Discarded file**
6296|0205|351004|666181|F.8.5|C|1|3|GP|

**Bad data file**
6296|0205|441201|666181|F.8.5|E|1|3|CS|
6296|0205|461210|666181|F.8.5|E|1|3|EM GW|
```

After running the script, when redirecting the output to a file, the output looks like this

```
6296|0205|351004|666181|F.8.5|C|1|3|GP| failed all WHEN clauses.
6296|0205|441201|666181|F.8.5|E|1|3|CS| ******************Error on  table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT. Actual Error :  ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated
6296|0205|461210|666181|F.8.5|E|1|3|EM GW| ******************Error on  table SCH_USER.TEMP_RESULT. Actual Error :  ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCH_USER.PK_TEMP_RESULT) violated
```

In the above scenario, it is possible that either bad data file or discarded file or both may not exist ( that would be good news, no errors when using sqlldr ).  I want to be able to handle both these scenarios gracefully using the script.

I hope that is possible.  Would you let me know, how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `FNR==1 { FileNum++ }` FNR is file record number, it resets after each file, using this condition script know what file it's working on
>
> `FileNum==1 { Bad[FNR] = $0 ; next }` if the script is processing the first file add the lines ($0) to an array indexed with record number (here lines), `next` skips the rest of the script to process the next record.
>
> `FileNum==2 {`  same for now second file
>
> `/^Record [0-9]+: Rejected/` now the script is processing the third file, pattern match each line starting "Record", space, one or more digits, ": Rejected".  For the matched lines, do the actions in the block.

UPDATE
`awk` operates files record by record (here the default record is the line).  With this approach it only looks for nonempty files, empty files will be skipped.  At a new file, the file record number `FNR` will be reset to 1.  Checking this value will indicate whether it finished one file and started the next (non-empty) file.  FileNum is a user defined variable.  This script is written with consideration of the input arguments.  First two files will be stored internally in arrays indexed by line numbers and while operating on the third file used as a reference.  It doesn't know whether files exist or not and will fail if files don't exist. It's probably better for to leave it to shell before invoking awk.

Comment: Thank you.  Still trying to understand what the first line does.  So, does it check if it is a new file by comparing if we are at the first record and if we are then it increments the FileNum variable? How does it determine the total number of files.  Does it happen in an implicit loop? Is FileNum also an awk specific variable or is it user defined ?.    So, if I want to check if the file exists, then should I do it inside the curly brackets after the check for FileNum == 1 or 2?  Sorry for the barrage of questions, but couldn't find this type of details when searching on the net.

Comment: @adbdkb all of those details and more are explained in the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks again @karakfa - I have gotten a high level understanding on how it executes the program, and your explanations will help me decipher the code.  The reason I want to check if the files exist within the script is that I will be using it on a daily basis after my sqlldr has run on schedule.  So, there maybe times when one or both bad and dsc files do not exist, so I wanted to check and perform the processing as applicable.  is that doable? And a valid idea ? Or do you still recommend doing it outside before invoking awk? Wouldn't that require me to have multiple awk scripts ?

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton.  I shall check out that book

Comment: @adbdkb you're welcome. wrt checking if a file exists - yes you can do that in awk but you haven't told us what you want to do if either file doesn't exist (or does exist but isn't readable). Edit your question to clarify your requirements and include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Also execute `awk --version` and include the output of that in your question. If you don't currently have gawk 4.1 at least then try to get a new (gawk 4.1.whatever) version of gawk.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OP may have left the building but for anyone else wanting know how to explicitly handle files that don't exist or cannot be opened for other reasons, here's the approach:

```
$ cat ../tst.awk
BEGIN {
    badFiles = rmvBadFiles()
    if ( badFiles != "" ) {
        printf "ERROR: cannot read from file(s):\n%s\n", badFiles | "cat>&2"
        # Add "exit 1" if you want to exit instead of continuing
    }
}
{ print FILENAME, $0 }

function rmvBadFiles(   _argind,_file,_line,_badFiles) {
    for (_argind=1; _argind < ARGC ; _argind++) {
        _file = ARGV[_argind]
        if (_file !~ /^([[:alnum:]_]+=.*|-?)$/) {
            if ( (getline _line < _file) < 0 ) {
                _badFiles = (_badFiles == "" ? "" : _badFiles "\n") _file
                ARGV[_argind] = ""
            }
            close(_file)
        }
    }
    return _badFiles
}
```

For example:

```
$ ls
file1  file2
$ cat file1
a
$ cat file2
b
$ awk -f ../tst.awk file1 garbage file2
file1 a
file2 b
ERROR: cannot read from file(s):
garbage
```

as opposed to the default behavior:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' file1 garbage file2
file1 a
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `garbage' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: No, not left the building yet :) - just trying to create the small testable data that can be used - will be able to upload it possibly today

Comment: your explanations and examples also helped a lot, but karafka initially explained the questions I originally had asked, so accepting that answer